# Hikashop USPS Shipping plugin does not seem to be computing shipping rates correctly

Tags: ecommerce, cms, plugin, joomla3

I have a near fatal issue where I can not get the USPS (United States Postal Service) Plugin written for Hikashop to return the proper USPS Postal Rates. According to the developers it "should be working just fine" and I have been told it works in their tests, however, I have been using USPS for my postage for a number of years, and I know immediately if a rate is being calculated correctly.

I have researched this through Google as well as the search box here, and it does not appear that there have been any HikaShop questions here, so I would rather wait to describe the issue in great detail once I know if there is even anyone that could possibly assist. Since the Hikashop Shopping Cart platform is not native to the US, the USPS Plugin was not developed with the native application, but rather added on at a later date so I do not know how much of my issue might be actual coding issues, interpretation of how to calculate a given rate issues, or possibly mathematical issues.

Hikashop is a Joomla CMS component which runs on an Apache web server. The USPS Plugin utilizes the USPS Webtools API. More extensive information will be added is there is a chance someone has experience with this and can assist.

Comment: I've added the [tag:hikashop] tag for you.